# What is the difference between JointJog msgs and JointTrajectory msg in ros2?

Tags: ros2, ros2-control, joint-trajectory-controller, ros2-controllers

I am learning ros2_control and have encountered a JointJog message. Can anyone explain in what context both messages are used? Is it possible to convert JointTrajectory msgs to Jointjog message?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK JointJog is not used of any of the controllers released with ros2_control but [MoveIt Servo](https://github.com/ros-controls/control_msgs/pull/47) uses/used it.